# Issue with finding text in specified columns

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm facing the problem of finding specified content (i.e. date or string text) in 3 specified columns (e.g. `row[0]` for check-in date, `row[1]` for check-out, `row[5]` for guests' full name). The script opens a dialogue window and asks to input a search query. Afterwards, suggestively, it checks all specified cells in a data range for a requested search query.

If it finds anything, then it shows a search results `ui.alert` with found results processed as:

```
var foundReservations = "\n" + "\nЗаезд: " + fullCheckInDate + "\nВыезд: " + fullCheckOutDate + "\nНомер: " + roomType + "\nТип размещения: " + numberOfGuests + "\n" + "\nКоличество ночей: " + formattedNumberOfNights + "\nЦена за ночь: " + formattedCostPerNight + "\nВнесённый депозит: " + formattedPrepaymentCost + "\n(" + formattedCostPerNight + " × " + formattedNumberOfNights + ")" + " – " + formattedPrepaymentCost + " = " + formattedUnpaidCost + " к оплате" + "\n" + "\nИмя и фамилия гостя: " + contactFullName + "\nМобильный телефон: " + contactPhone + "\nЭлектронная почта: " + contactEmail + "\n" + fullReservationNotes;
reservationsSearchResults += foundReservations; // Собираем воедино все найденные бронирования.
```

Full source code:

```
function FindReservationsBySpecifiedDetails() {
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var startRow = 2; // Строка с первым бронированием для начала обработки.
    var numRows = sheet.getLastRow()-1; // Количество строк с бронированиями для обработки.
    var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 11); // Охват столбцов для обработки ячеек, в данном случае с 1-го по 12-ый.
    var data = dataRange.getValues(); // Получить значение ячеек в каждой ячейке каждой строке в рамках столбцов, охваченных верхним кодом.
    var statusConfirmationSent = "Подтверждение отправлено";
    var statusConfirmationNotSent = "Подтверждение не отправлено";
    /* Поехали. */
    var step1 = ui.prompt("Поиск бронирований", "Чтобы начать поиск бронирований по (1) дате заезда, (2) дате выезда, (3) номеру бронированию и (4) имени и фамилии гостя, введите запрос. Например, 03/07/2016.", ui.ButtonSet.OK);
    var step1Button = step1.getSelectedButton();
    var searchQuery = step1.getResponseText();
    var formattedSearchQuery = "«" + searchQuery + "»";
    var numberOfReservationsFound = "";
    var reservationsSearchResults = "";
    if (step1Button == ui.Button.OK) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
            for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
                var row = data[i];
                var checkInDate = new Date(row[0]);
                var checkOutDate = new Date(row[1]);
                var formattedCheckInDate = Utilities.formatDate(checkInDate, "GMT+0300", "dd.MM.yyyy");
                var formattedCheckOutDate = Utilities.formatDate(checkOutDate, "GMT+0300", "dd.MM.yyyy");
                var fullCheckInDate = Utilities.formatDate(checkInDate, "GMT+0300", "dd.MM.yyyy") + " (с 14:00)";
                var fullCheckOutDate = Utilities.formatDate(checkOutDate, "GMT+0300", "dd.MM.yyyy") + " (до 12:00)";
                var reservationNumber = [i+2] + "0" + checkInDate.getFullYear(); // С 18:35, 26.09.2016 (МСК) используется универсальный формат номера бронирований (до этого момента он формировался по формуле [i+2]).
                var roomType = "«" + row[2] + "»";
                var numberOfGuests = row[3];
                var numberOfNights = Math.round(Math.abs((checkOutDate.getTime() - checkInDate.getTime())/(24*60*60*1000)));
                var costPerNight = row[4];
                var prepaymentCost = row[8];
                var unpaidCost = (costPerNight*numberOfNights)-prepaymentCost;
                var comissionFeeForPayingWithBankCard = "0.02"; // Комиссия при оплате стоимости проживания с помощью банковской карты.
                var formattedComissionFeeForPayingWithBankCard = comissionFeeForPayingWithBankCard*100 + "%";
                var fullComissionFeeForPayingWithBankCard = formattedComissionFeeForPayingWithBankCard + " комиссии";
                var totalUnpaidCostPaidWithBankCard = unpaidCost+(unpaidCost*comissionFeeForPayingWithBankCard);
                var formattedNumberOfNights = numberOfNights + " ночей"; // Количество ночей проживания.
                var formattedCostPerNight = costPerNight + " руб.";
                var formattedPrepaymentCost = prepaymentCost + " руб.";
                var formattedUnpaidCost = unpaidCost + " руб."; // Сумма, которую необходимо оплатить гостю по приезде.
                var formattedTotalUnpaidCostPaidWithBankCard = totalUnpaidCostPaidWithBankCard + " руб.";
                var contactFullName = row[5];
                var contactGivenName = contactFullName.split(" ").slice(0, -1).join(" ");
                var contactPhone = row[6];
                var contactEmail = row[7];
                var reservationNotes = row[11];
                /* Не показываем строку с примечаниями к бронированию в случае их отсутствия. */
                var fullReservationNotes = "\nПримечания к бронированию: " + reservationNotes + "\n";
                    if (data[i][j].toString().indexOf(searchQuery) > -1) {
                    if (reservationNotes == "") {fullReservationNotes == ""}
                    var foundReservations = "\n" + "\nЗаезд: " + fullCheckInDate + "\nВыезд: " + fullCheckOutDate + "\nНомер: " + roomType + "\nТип размещения: " + numberOfGuests + "\n" + "\nКоличество ночей: " + formattedNumberOfNights + "\nЦена за ночь: " + formattedCostPerNight + "\nВнесённый депозит: " + formattedPrepaymentCost + "\n(" + formattedCostPerNight + " × " + formattedNumberOfNights + ")" + " – " + formattedPrepaymentCost + " = " + formattedUnpaidCost + " к оплате" + "\n" + "\nИмя и фамилия гостя: " + contactFullName + "\nМобильный телефон: " + contactPhone + "\nЭлектронная почта: " + contactEmail + "\n" + fullReservationNotes;
                    reservationsSearchResults += foundReservations; // Собираем воедино все найденные бронирования.
            }
        }
        // return(count);
    }
    var step2 = ui.alert("Результаты поиска бронирований", "По вашему запросу найдено " + numberOfReservationsFound + " результат(ов):" + reservationsSearchResults, ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
    var step2Button = step2.getSelectedButton();
    /* Когда пользователь нажимает «Да» на шаге № 2. */
    if (step2 == ui.Button.YES) {
    ui.alert("Результаты поиска бронирований были приняты пользователем на шаге представления результатов поиска.");
    Logger.log("Результаты поиска бронирований были приняты пользователем на шаге представления результатов поиска.");
    }
    /* Когда пользователь нажимает «Нет» на шаге № 2. */
    else if (step2 == ui.Button.NO) {
    ui.alert("Результаты поиска бронирований были отклонены пользователем на шаге представления результатов поиска.");
    Logger.log("Результаты поиска бронирований были отклонены пользователем на шаге представления результатов поиска.");
    }
    /* Когда пользователь нажимает «Закрыть» на шаге № 2. */
    else if (step2 == ui.Button.CLOSE) {
    ui.alert("Окно с представленными результатами поиска бронирований были закрыты пользователем.");
    Logger.log("Окно с представленными результатами поиска бронирований были закрыты пользователем.");
    }
    } else {
    ui.alert("По запросу " + formattedSearchQuery + " не найдено ни одного бронирования. Пожалуйста, попробуйте задать другой запрос.");
    }
    if (step1Button == ui.Button.CLOSE) {
    ui.alert("Поиск бронирований был прерван пользователем на шаге № 1. Чтобы найти бронирования, попробуйте запустить процедуру поиска снова.");
    }
}
```

However:

1. It never finds anything. (`ui.alert` with search results is always empty).
2. After I close a window with none results, it starts iteratively popping up. I bet it occurs because of incorrectly setup if loop but I failed to fix it.

I haven't found much on StackOverflow that helps.

How can I resolve this issue? Is there anything with the rows of code which check cells for containing searching values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what's going to happen on this line

```
(reservationNotes == "") {fullReservationNotes == ""}
```

because I'm guessing that you want it to say this instead.

```
(reservationNotes == "") {fullReservationNotes = "";}
```

So no semicolon and the second one should be an assignment.  The first one is a comparison.

I think I've seen this code before and it humbled me to realize how difficult it would to go to school in another country where all their text would come out in my editor as this "?????????? ?????? ????????????", "?? ?????? ??????? ??????? ".

Comment: Yes, I've already edited this row. Concerning the comments, I use Russian to make it more elaborative for my colleagues.